Canonical way to test if value is among values in Java
Python:
if a in (b, c, d):
   ...

JavaScript:
if ([b, c, d].contains(a)) {
    ...
}

What is the canonical syntax for doing this in Java ?
The goals are:

Test if a given value is equal to any among a set of other values
The set of values should be forgotten as soon as the if's condition is done being evaluated - so, everything should be contained in the if's parentheses
Execution should be cheap
The value to test against (here, a) should not be repeated, as it may be an expensive or side-effected expression rather than a variable

I am ideally looking for a solution compatible with Java 8.
Because of the second point above, which as a reminder is that the set of values should be forgotten as soon as the if's condition is done being evaluated, CONSTANT.contains() is not a solution, since the nature of a constant means it 1) is calculated long before arriving to the if statement, 2) persists after the condition is evaluated.
The question currently marked as duplicate to this one asks how to test among constants, which this question is not about.

depends on the Collection types you use, on whether or not your classes implement equals and hashcode, ...

Something like List.of(b,c,d).contains(a) may be a semantically equivalent solution.

Something like this would work in Java 8
I used string for simplicity but any type that implements a comparison operator would work
if(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").contains("a")) {
   //Code
}

This would be a linear search in O(n) time which is also what you have in the examples you gave

The examples given use a tuple in python and a list in javascript so it's pretty obvious what data structure the question targets...

@Nifil I could have used a set in Python (which the compiler turns into a frozenset in that particular situation) but in python it turns out it's pretty much the same performance-wise. Unless the set is large, in which case it's better to use a set than a tuple, but in that case it's probably not a great practice to have it in the middle of your code and not as a declared variable or constant.
